# What can be done to optimize the amount of time it takes to leave a method and empty out the stack of local variables?

Tags: c++, optimization, stack

I have a method which is responsible for taking an openGl triangle mesh and converting it to a 3ds file. This method is called `exportShape()`. To perform this conversion `exportShape()` creates a bunch of very large vectors and hash_maps. Currently, getting from the last line of `exportShape()` to the next line of code from where `exportShape()` was called can take up to 5 minutes. I’m sure that all this time is spent emptying out the very large stack of local variables because if I move all the local vectors and hash_maps to global scope the method exists instantly as I would expect.

Why am I able to populate all these local data structures in just a few seconds whereas popping them off the stack takes minutes? How can I optimized the process of leaving my `exportShape()` and clearing out the stack?

**Edit:**

The objects which are being deleted contain only strings, doubles and ints - nothing with a custom destructor.

I pretty much solved my own problem. Running in release mode is a *huge* performance increase (~20x). Nevertheless, the process still hangs for a few seconds. Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: Most of the time is probably destroying the elements of your `vectors/hash_maps`. So maybe you should tell us what you put into them, and if those object have expensive destructors.

Comment: So, you should give us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your function `exportShape()`.

Comment: If you move your stack objects to global scope, their destructors will not be called until program exit - this explains the difference in performance.

Comment: "The objects which are being deleted contain only strings, doubles and ints - nothing with a custom destructor." - strings have a custom destructor.

Comment: @Mysticial, do you think that would be the bottleneck?

Comment: @Amichai Hard to say without an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the first instance is that you're using a debug allocator, which marks freed memory with a bit pattern (e.g. `0xfdfdfdfd`) to aid in detecting accesses to freed memory.  This obviously takes time as it must iterate over all the freed memory.

To speed things up further, you could use a scoped allocator e.g. the [Boost Pool Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html); see also [Creating a scoped custom memory pool/allocator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670828/creating-a-scoped-custom-memory-pool-allocator)